# JqueryMobile navigation Title problem

Tags: jquery-mobile

here is the html file which calls the above method. When call "callAjax" is clicked, i can get the listview displayed. These listview when clicked will not show navigation bar title.

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" >
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
        <h1>NDUS Directory</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" >  
        <div id ="divsearch" class ="LogoImage" >
            <img src="Images/logo.gif" align="middle" />
        </div>
        <p></p>

        <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value=""  />
        <label for="lname">Last Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value=""  />
        <p></p>   

        <input id="callAjax" type="button" value="Search" data-theme="b" />

        <!--  TO SHOW PEOCESSING LAG INFORMATION -->

        <span id="sp" class = "spanRed"></span> 
            <div id="resultLog">

            </div>
            <div id="ajaxBusy" class ="busyAJAX">
                <p>
                    <img src="Images/progress.gif">
                </p>
            </div>


            <span id="placeholder"></span>

            <ul id = "idul" data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-inset="true">
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

[image]here is a sample ajax call which dynamically generates the listview. The code does its job..but the window which shows the details about the listview(when clicked) does not get any title for the navigation bar. In code..it needs to display the txt.firstname and txt.lastname.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "DirectoryData.asmx/TestSearch",
    data: argument,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#resultLog").html("Loading" + '<img src="Images/progress.gif" />');
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        var items = [];

        $("#unfinshed").remove();

        var public_tweets = JSON.parse(msg.d);

        if (public_tweets.length > 0) {
            // remove older values
            $("#placeholder").after('<ol id="unfinshed" data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-inset="true" data-dividertheme="c"></ol>');
            $('<li data-role="list-divider">Records found: ' + public_tweets.length + '</li>').appendTo("#unfinshed");

            // $('#unfinshed').empty();
            for (var x = 0; x < public_tweets.length; x++) {
                var txt = public_tweets[x];
                var imageName;

                if (txt.type == "Faculty") {
                    imageName = "Images/BusinessPerson.png";
                } else {
                    imageName = "Images/StudentPerson.png";
                }
                //<img src="images/gf.png" alt="France" class="ui-li-icon">

                $('<li><img src="' + imageName + '" class="ui-li-icon">
                    <a href="#" >' + txt.firstname + ' ' + txt.lastname + '
                    </a><p></p><p>' + txt.title + '</p>' +
                    '<ul data-theme="c" data-inset="true">' +
                    '<li><span class="dirHeaderFont">' + 'Institution:</span><p></p>
                    <span class="footerTextFont">' + txt.institution + '</span></li>' +
                    '<li><span class="dirHeaderFont">' + 'Department:</span><p></p>
                    <span class="footerTextFont">' + txt.department + '</span></li>' +
                    '<li><span class="dirHeaderFont">' + 'Title:</span><p></p>
                    <span class="footerTextFont">' + txt.title + '</span></li>' +
                    '<li data-icon="grid"><span class="dirHeaderFont">' + 
                    'Phone:</span><p></p><span class="footerTextFont">
                    <a href="tel:' + txt.phonenumber + '">' + txt.phonenumber + 
                    '</a></span></li>' +
                    '<li data-icon="search"><span class="dirHeaderFont">' + 
                    'Email:</span><p></p><span class="footerTextFont">
                    <a href="mailto:' + txt.email + '">' + txt.email + 
                    '</a></span></li>' +
                    '<li><span class="dirHeaderFont">' + 'Active:</span><p>
                    </p><span class="footerTextFont">' + txt.active + 
                    '</span></li>' + '</ul>' +
            '</li>').appendTo("#unfinshed");

            }
            $("#unfinshed").page();

        } else {
            // display no records found
            $("#placeholder").after('<ul id="unfinshed" data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-inset="true"></ul>');
            $('<li>' + 'No records found' + '</li>').appendTo("#unfinshed");
            $("#unfinshed").page();

        } // end of public_tweets check

        $("#resultLog").html(' '); // remove the loading image

    }
}); // end of ajax


$("#resultLog").ajaxError(function (event, request, settings, exception) {
    $("#resultLog").html("Error connecting to database. Try again later.");
    //$("#resultLog").html("Error connecting to database. Try again later.: " + settings.url + "<br />HTPP Code: " + request.status);
});
```

Comment: I don't see where you're adding the header navigation code, could you supply this as well? Are you setting it after the page transition/ajax call?

Comment: I jsut added the hrml code from which the javascript gets called. Any help is greatly apprecited.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a custom title like this:

```
$("div:jqmData(role='header')").prepend('<h1>Custom Title</h1>');
```

Might need to tinker with it a tad but it works

UPDATE:

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/trdYP/51/

JS:

```
$("div:jqmData(role='header') > h1").replaceWith('<h1 class="ui-title" tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-level="1">New Title</h1>');
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="header"> 
        <h1 >Home</h1> 
    </div> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Home Page</li> 
            <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>  
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Page 2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2"> 
    <div data-role="header"> 
        <h1 >Page 2</h1> 
    </div> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Home Page</li> 
            <li><a href="#home">Home Page</a></li>  
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe before $("#unfinshed").page();

Comment: instead of div try passing the id and maybe this might be in a live() as well, but I tested the code and it does add the title to the header it's just the implementation that might be a challenge

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code...I am unable to understand your suggested solution.